# Directly quoting a source who also has a cited source

Tags: academic-writing

When you are directly quoting a source who also has a cited source in the sentence or sentences you are using what is the best course of action?

Comment: How does the source being quoted cite its source?  (Inline or in a footnote?)  And is there any particular style guide you're expected to follow (MLA, Chicago, etc)?

Comment: This question is answered in my answer here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/13014/5645